# python 3.1 with pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I am now moving to eclipse for my python development. I have pydev installed but it is showing grammar support up to python version 3.0. My question is can I use python 3.1 with 3.0 grammar? Has the grammar changed from version 3.0 to 3.1?

I am using eclipse 3.4.2 and pydev 1.4.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

grammar hasn't changed, some [modules have](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html).