# Python - Is the grammar for 3.0 the same as 3.3?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, python-3.3

I noticed when setting up a PyDev project in Eclipse that the latest grammar version available is 3.0. However, I noticed in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305218/python-3-1-with-pydev) that the grammar from 3.0 doesn't change when moving to 3.1. Is the same true between 3.0 and 3.3? Thank you much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no changes in 3.2, as [PEP 3003](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3003/) was in effect, but 3.0-3.3 adds `yield from` which was invalid in 3.2, and also once again allows `u'...'` for Unicode string literals (this was valid in 2.x but not in 3.x until 3.3). See http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html. If you don't use either of those features, you should be fine with a 3.0 grammar.

If you do use those features (`yield from` is handy but you're unlikely to have `u`-tagged strings if you've been coding in Python 3.x) then that might get improperly colored and/or flagged as an error. I don't use PyDev and don't know what it actually uses the grammar for; you might give it a try anyway since the syntax differences are so small.